# Flexbox Image Gallery with Title Holder in the middle?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have a responsive image gallery of 3 images that are vertically placed with a title holder centered above the image gallery at all screen sizes. I would like the image gallery to change to a horizontal orientation when the screen reaches the breakpoint for larger screens. I have gotten the images to be responsive but I cannot get the title holder to be centered above.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="projects-section">
     <div class="projects-title-container">
          <p class="projects-title">Projects</p>
          <div class="bar-under-projects-title"></div>
     </div>    
     <ul class="project-picture-gallery">
          <li class="project-item" id="light-shoulders-picture"></li>
          <li class="project-item" id="Wildfire-picture"></li>
          <li class="project-item" id="TheIMDBOfSportsPicture"></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.projects-section, .project-picture-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.projects-section {
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

.project-picture-gallery {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#light-shoulders-picture {
    background: url('/HTML/LightShouldersOfficialLogo/LightShouldersOfficialLogo.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50.806451%;
    height: 0;
}
#Wildfire-picture {
    background: url('/HTML/WildfireOfficialLogo/WildfireOfficialLogo.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 34.7399411%;
    height: 0;
}
#TheIMDBOfSportsPicture {
    background: url('/HTML/LightShouldersOfficialLogo/LightShouldersOfficialLogo.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50.806451%;
    height: 0;
}

.projects-title-container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}
.projects-title {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.bar-under-projects-title {
    background-color: #B34443;
    height: 6px;
    width: 50px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .projects-section, .project-picture-gallery {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1030px) {
    .projects-section, .project-picture-gallery {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .projects-section {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .project-picture-gallery {
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
}

.project-picture-gallery {
  list-style: none;
}

.project-picture-gallery li {
  margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

.project-picture-gallery li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}


@media all and (min-width: 1030px) {
  .projects-section {
    min-width: 768px;
  }
}
```

I do not understand what I need to do to the title holder to make it centered above the image gallery at all times. Any ideas?

This is what it's supposed to look like when the screen is larger but I do not have a picture of what it's supposed to look like as a default which is smaller screens. The smaller screen should have the title in the same way, but the list items are in a column instead:

[image]

Comment: An image of what this is *supposed* to look like would be useful.

Comment: Sorry about that. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to keep the title centered on the screen at all times, but want the images laid out horizontally on wider screens, and vertically on smaller screens.

The code you provided in your question doesn't reproduce the problem. However, here's a generic solution that may help you (and others).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="projects">Projects</div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100"></li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.gallery {
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 500px ) {
    ul { 
        flex-direction: column; 
        align-items: center; 
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mr44qd8z/ (re-size screen for effect)